Unable to delete folder on a network share from Windows 10
I have a Windows 10 22H2 host that accesses network shares on a server. I do not have access to the server.
When I try and delete a  folder on the share, it displays "Folder In Use" notification.
I have attempted to use PowerShell as an Administrator, set the execution policy to unrestricted, and set the location to the network folder. Attempting to use Remove-Item [filepath] -Recurse -Force returns:

Cannot remove item [filepath]: The process cannot access the file '[filepath]' because it is being used by another process.

I used Get-SmbOpenFile in all subfolders and nothing is returned, so I am unable to use Close-SmbOpenFile. I understand that using the SMB cmdlets may not be the best way to close a folder.
I can provide more information if needed.
EDIT: I have since attempted OpenFiles, takeown, and icacls and still have not been able to delete the folder.

You can use Sysinternals Handle.exe to search for the path that is "in use".

Due to company policy, I am limited to a list of approved software tools and unfortunately, Sysinternals is not on the list of supported applications. Thank you very much for the help

I do not have direct access to the servers because policy this is a really big problem, because only from the server you can find who or what is actually locking the file.

This needs to be resolved from the server, not the client. You need to engage with the administrator of the server...

Since it's a network share, the file could be locked by anyone in the network who has access to it, not necessarily by the user who is complaining.
I do not have direct access to the servers because policy.

This is a really big problem, because only on the server itself you can look up who or what is actually locking the file (and you can also close open connections to it, thus removing the lock).

It is a problem, but one that rarely comes up for my position. I've been working as a SysAdmin for 3 months now and this is the first time it has been an issue. Thank you very much for your response.
